# Issue loading PrimeFaces 5.2 in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, primefaces

I am seeing a strange problem with the latest version of PrimeFaces 5.2 and Internet Explorer.  When I test locally, the primefaces library loads fine, all the controls and input fields and ajax calls all function normally across all browsers.

However when I deploy to my customer's production environment and open the website in Internet Explorer (version 10) the website does not appear to load any of the primefaces styling for input fields or ajax calls.  For example, the input fields are no longer styled, and the ajax updates do not occur so that when I click on a checkbox for example, the updated button has to be clicked twice before the re-rendering is completed.

When I installed firefox or chrome this was not an issue, but for the production environment's internet explorer, this was a problem.  Does anyone know what could possibly be causing the issue?  Could there be a specific setting that is causing this to occur?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Does anyone know what could possibly be causing the issue?"_ Yes _"Could there be a specific setting that is causing this to occur?"_ Compatibility modus

Comment: I tried turning that both on and off without success

Comment: @Kukeltje - my apologies, I had only tried disabling it for the "intranet sites".  It appears that compatibility mode was enabled for "all sites" and once that was turned off everything loaded correctly.  Can you submit an answer here so I can accept it and explain why this is causing a problem?  If my client is unsatisfied with this outcome it would be helpful to have a technical explanation for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what this guy Kukeltje said above, its the compatibility mode.  Thats the answer.  Leaving this here so everyone can benefit from it.

As to what the technical reason is, I have no idea.  I will add this, that if you add the following meta tag in your header you can force the compatibility mode OFF.  If you have primefaces 4 and up, I believe, the facet methodology will force the meta tag to appear as the first tag, which is necessary for this to work:

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
</f:facet>
```